# Inverse sum of matrices

Tags: matrix, maple

I am totally new to Maple and I would like to solve the following linear system:

```
Y=BX
```

where `X` is the input, `Y` is the output and B the transfer function which has these form:

```
B :=(t) ->  matrix(A0)+matrix(A1)*f1(t)+matrix(B1)*f2(t)

A0 := matrix(3, 3, [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]);
A1 := matrix(3, 3, [1, 1/2, (1/2)*sqrt(3), 1/2, 1, (1/2)*sqrt(3), (1/2)*sqrt(3), 1/2, 2]);
B1 := matrix(3, 3, [1, 1/2, -(1/2)*sqrt(3), -1/2, 1, (1/2)*sqrt(3), (-sqrt(3))*(1/2), 1/2, 2]);

f1 := (t) -> cos(omega*t)
f2 := (t) -> sin(omega*t)

omega:=0.95;
```

However, now I want to obtain the input vector given the output, hence I need to invert `B` since:

```
X = B^-1 Y
```

I would appreciate a hint in order to obtain the symbolic expression of the inverse of `B`. However, when I do

```
inverse(B(t)) :  nothing happens
inverse(matrix(B(t))) :  Error, (in matrix) invalid argument 
solve(x = B(t), t): Error, (in SolveTools:-complexity) invalid input: numer expects its 1st argument
```

I would like it as the following form if possible:

```
B^-1 := A0' + A1'*f1(t) + B1'*f2(t)
```

Where `A0'`, `A1'` and `B1'` are the inverse matrices.

Comment: This question is about math really and not programming. Try the [Mathematics.SE] site.

Comment: But I still need to learn to compute simbolic matrices

Comment: That would be the secondary to knowing how to compute the inverses. _If_ there is an inverse of the form you ask then coding `B^-1` would be easy (using the equation provided). After you find the component matrices `A0'` `A1'` and `A2'` using math you can ask the coding question here.

Comment: But I still can not get the expression of B in simbolic form and hence can not compute the inverse.

Comment: What you are looking for is `B^-1(t)` symbolically so you don't have to invert the matrix at each step. Is this correct?

Comment: So A0', A1' and B1' are not the direct inverses of A0,A1 and B1

Comment: No. (A+B)^-1 is not equal to A^-1+B^-1. There might  be an expression but you need to ask in the math forum for a better chance of a good answer.

Comment: Look the update please

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [tangent half angle substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula#The_tangent_half-angle_substitution_in_integral_calculus) to create (in pseudo-code)

```
z = TAN(ω·t/2) = TAN(φ/2)
φ = ω·t = 2 ATAN(z)

       | 2*(z+1)/(1+z^2)          (z+1)/(1+z^2)-1/2  √3*(1-z)/(1+z^2)-√3/2  |
B(z) = | 1/2+(1-z)/(1+z^2)        2*(z+1)/(1+z^2)-1   √3*(z+1)/(1+z^2)-√3/2 |
       | 1-√3/2+√3*(1-z)/(1+z^2)  (z+1)/(1+z^2)-1/2  4*(z+1)/(1+z^2)-2      |
```

which then you can obtain `IB(z)=inverse(B(z))` to use as `X = IB(tan(omega*t/2))*Y`

Comment: Please check the coefficients yourself using [tag:maple] and the symbolic substitution above.